# Build up a string to be passed to call operator

Tags: powershell

I need to build a string that is actually a command-line, and then execute the contents of that command-line. I'd hoped the call operator (&) would help, but it appears not. Here is a simple contrived example. The following works as expected, it pings a website:

```
$command = "ping"
$website = "www.bbc.co.uk"
& $command $website
```

however if I change it to this:

```
$command = "ping"
$website = "www.bbc.co.uk"
$cmd = "$command $website"
& $cmd
```

I get an error:

> The term 'ping www.bbc.co.uk' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Is there a way to dynamically build up a command-line as a string, and then execute it?

Comment: use `iex $cmd` instead

Comment: Thanks @CB., that does work for my contrived example. However, it seems my contrived example is not representative enough. What I actually want to do is call a .exe so in reality I'm doing something more like this:
$cmd = "C:\somepath\someprogram.exe"
iex $cmd
the output from that is simply:
  C:\somepath\someprogram.exe
i.e. its not executing someprogram.exe. Any idea why?

Comment: @CB. As my trivial example above was not representative enough i have re-posted over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453865/execute-an-exe-using-the-call-operator

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you need to use `Invoke-Expression` (which is just like `eval`), instead of the call operator. Note that you also need to ensure that all your quoting is correct in that case. E.g.

```
$cmd = "'$command' '$website'"
```

would work in your trivial example, unless `$command` or `$website` contained single quotes. The problem here is essentially that everything you put into the string is subject to the usual parsing rules of PowerShell.

Generally, if you can, stay as far away from `Invoke-Expression` as you can. There are a few problems that need it, but invoking external programs ... not so much.

A much better alternative, especially if you have an arbitrary number of arguments, is to just collect the arguments in an array and use the splat operator (note the `@` in the code example below):

```
$command = 'ping'
$arguments = '-t','www.bbc.co.uk'
&$command @arguments
```

This ensures that arguments are properly quoted when necessary and generally avoids *a lot* of headaches you're going to get with `Invoke-Expression`.

(Side note: Whenever you have a problem in PowerShell and *think* »Oh, I'm just going to use a string«, it's often time to rethink that. This includes handling file names, or command lines. PowerShell has objects, reducing it to the capabilities of earlier shells just yields the same pain you have elsewhere too, e.g. multiple levels of escaping, sometimes with different syntaxes, etc. And most of the time there are better ways of solving the problem.)

Comment: Thanks @Joey, very helpful indeed. Turns out that my trivial example above was not representative enough of the real problem I'm having so I have rewritten and posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453865/execute-an-exe-using-the-call-operator

Comment: I'd say your new question still exactly matches the answer. Take a look at the second half of the answer.

Comment: Hi Joey, then I'm afraid I'm missing something because the first part of my second thread attempts to do what you have described here (i.e. passing arguments as an array) and does not work. As I say, I'm missing something, but I'm afraid I don't know what?

Comment: You more or less used the first two lines (storing command as string, arguments as array), but ignored the *actually crucial point* of using the splat operator.

Comment: GAARRGHH. You're right, sorry. let me give it a bash and get back to you.

Comment: You're right, thanks Joey. The *real* problem I'm now facing is the presence of spaces in the path to the executable. I have updated the second thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453865/execute-an-exe-using-the-call-operator) accordingly.