# Execute an .exe using the call operator

Tags: powershell

I need to build a string that is actually a command-line, and then execute the contents of that command-line. I'd hoped the call operator (&) would help, but it appears not.

```
$cmd = "`'c:\some path with spaces in it\java.exe`'"
$arguments = "-jar","`"C:\some Other Path\MyJar.jar`""
& $cmd @arguments
```

(Very helpfully suggested by @joey here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28453250/201657)

This produced an error:

> & : The term '"C:\some path with spaces in it\java.exe"' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I then discovered that if I put the executable in a path that doesn't contain spaces then I can change my code to:

```
$command = "C:\somepathWithoutSpaces\java.exe"
$arguments = '-jar','"C:\someOtherPath\Cronacle.car"'
&$command @arguments
```

and it works (note the lack of escape character to put in a delimiter).

So I guess the real question is, how do I put delimiters around the call to "c:\some path with spaces in it\java.exe" so that this just works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have should work, apart from quoting issues. Note that the string should contain the path to the executable, without any additional quoting. Also the arguments don't need to be quoted inside the string. That's what I tried making clear in my last answer, that PowerShell does this stuff automatically when used correctly.

If it still complains about not finding the executable, then I'd say that it isn't there.

```
PS> $cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'
PS> $arguments = ,'-version'
PS> & $cmd @arguments
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

works fine for me, despite the space.

Again, do not add additional quotes to either the program or the arguments:

```
PS> $cmd = '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe"'
PS> & $cmd @arguments
& : The term '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
```

Note the extra (and unnecessary, even wrong) quote within the string. Same holds for arguments:

```
PS> $arguments = ,'''-version'''
PS> & $cmd @arguments
Error: Could not find or load main class '-version'
```

Comment: OK, my heads in a bit of a muddle but let me try and understand that and I'll get back to you. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Confirmed, I've got it working now. Thanks again Joey, very much appreciated. I've learnt a heck of a lot from this - really pleased.

Comment: Tried to execute Java in a place where it doesn't exist?